# Hibernate Allow private constructor

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Can anyone help me on this...

I created a pojo with a private no-args constructor ( going against JPA recomendation that we need to use a protected or public constructor )
and i'm able to retrive, update, delete, insert data.

Why this is possible ?

```java
@Entity @Table(name = "tb_pessoa")
public class Pessoa {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "pessoa_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "pessoa_nome")
    private String nome;

    private Pessoa() {}
}


@ExtendWith(DAOExtension.class)
public class PessoaDAOTest extends BaseDAOTest {

    @Test @SQL(scripts = {
        "scripts/inserir-joao.sql",
        "scripts/inserir-joao2.sql"
    })

    public void deve_consultar_pessoas_salvas() {
        List<Pessoa> pessoas = getEntityManager().createQuery("select p from Pessoa p").getResultList();
        Assertions.assertEquals(4, pessoas.size());

        Pessoa p1 = getEntityManager().find(Pessoa.class, 1 L);
        Assertions.assertNotNull(p1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

According to [Hibernate documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#entity-pojo-constructor) (emphasis mine):

> The entity class should have a no-argument constructor. Both Hibernate and JPA require this.
>
> JPA requires that this constructor be defined as public or protected. Hibernate, for the most part, does not care about the constructor visibility, **as long as the system SecurityManager allows overriding the visibility setting**. That said, the constructor should be defined with at least package visibility if you wish to leverage runtime proxy generation.